# get value from cropdetect

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have been able to parse the output of `ffmpeg cropdetect` with a batch file in Windows 7 to get crop=640:480:0:0 but the process goes too far and processes the last mp4 or mkv file twice.
I run the first for loop to get a list of mkv or mp4 files in the folder and run a process `:gin`.
The second `for` loop to run `ffmpeg` skipping ahead 30 seconds and run `cropdetect` on only one second of video with the long file of 60 plus entrys of
`[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0000000002ef8f00] x1:0 x2:1279 y1:0 y2:719 w:1280 h:720 x:0 y:0 pts:1081 t:1.081000 crop=1280:720:0:0`
going to `tmp.txt`
`Tail` gives me the last line of `tmp.txt` and outputs to a new text file `tmp1.txt`
The last `for` loop looks at `tmp1.txt` and returns the 14th. token of crop=1280:720:0:0

This is a Zeranoe Windows static build and I have tails for windows installed.

I have tried...
different for loops

```
for %g in (*.mp4, *.mkv) do set this=%g
```

```
for /f "delims=*" %g in ('dir /b /o:n *.mp4, *.mkv') set this=%g
```

I have also tried to have `tail` output overwrite the input with `tail -1 tmp.txt > tmp.txt`

this all works but is not as elegant.
what I have so far,

```
for /f "delims=*" %%g in ('dir /b /o:-n *.m??') do set cdet=%%g&& call :gin

:gin

ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 00:0:30.000 -i "%cdet%" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null -2>&1 | findstr /c:"crop=" > tmp.txt 

tail -1 tmp.txt  >tmp1.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=14" %%a in ("tmp1.txt") do set line=%%a

del tmp*.txt

echo %line%
```

I would like to see if there is a better way to do this without creating temp files and overwriting already processed files.

for those interested the updated script is:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /a-d /b /o:-n *.mkv 2^>nul') do set "cdet=%%I" && call :gin

goto :end
:gin
ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 00:0:30.000 -i "%cdet%" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | findstr /c:"crop=" >tmp1.txt
for /f "usebackq tokens=14" %%a in ("tmp1.txt") do set line=%%a
del tmp*.txt
echo %line%
pause
:end
exit /b
```

Comment: @Mofi I should have realized I needed the goto to end processing thanks

Comment: @Mofi It's fixed thanks

Answer (score 2):

The last file is processed twice because of `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` is missing after first `for` loop to avoid a fall through to the command lines of the subroutine after first `for` finished. See also: [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

The batch file can be optimized most likely with avoiding the subroutine completely according to provided data with using this code:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.m?? /A-D-H /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ('"ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -ss 00:0:30.000 -i "%%I" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /c:"crop=""') do set "CropData=%%J"
    call echo crop=%%CropData%%
)
endlocal
```

Command **FOR** with option `/F` and a command line specified between `'` results in starting one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the specified command line. So executed by **FOR** is with Windows being installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir *.m?? /A-D-H /B /O-N 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches

- in current directory
- just for non-hidden files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.m??`
- and outputs in bare format because of option `/B` just the names of the files without file path
- ordered reverse by file name because of option `/O-N` (for whatever reason).

The file names are output to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of background command process. This output is captured by **FOR** respectively the command process running the batch file.

It is possible that no directory entry matches the specified search criteria resulting in printing an error message by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** (standard error) which is redirected by **FOR** to **STDERR** of command process running the batch file. This error message can be suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** by started `cmd.exe` running in background.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` processes the captured standard output of started command process line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself as follows:

1. Empty lines are always ignored by **FOR**, but empty lines do not occur here.
2. A line is split up by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters and just first space/tab separated string is assigned to specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is not wanted in this case as the file names could contain spaces and the entire file name should be assigned to loop variable `I` and not just the file name part up to first space. For that reason `delims=` defines an empty list of delimiters to turn off line splitting completely.
3. Next **FOR** checks if first substring, i.e. entire file name in this case, starts with default end of line character `;` which is a valid character for first character of a file name. For that reason `eol=|` redefines end of line character to vertical bar which no file name can contain according to Microsoft documentation [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

For each file the outer **FOR** executes the inner **FOR** which runs again in background a command process for example with the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -ss 00:0:30.000 -i "C:\Temp\My vido.mp4" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f - null 2>&1 | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /c:"crop=""
```

The started Windows command processor instanced running in background removes in this case first and last `"` before executing the remaining command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -ss 00:0:30.000 -i "C:\Temp\My vido.mp4" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f - null 2>&1 | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /c:"crop="
```

`ffmpeg.exe` outputs information like this one as far as I know to handle **STDERR** (standard error) instead of **STDOUT** (standard output). For that reason `2>&1` is needed to redirect output written to handle **STDERR** of background command process by `ffmpeg.exe` to handle **STDOUT** of background command process which is redirected next to **STDIN** of **FINDSTR** searching case sensitive for literal string `crop=` anywhere in a line and outputs the entire line containing this string to **STDOUT** of started background command process.

Those lines are captured by **FOR** and processed one after the other as described above. But this time `delims==` modifies the list of string delimiters to just equal sign character which results in splitting up a line like

```
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0000000002ef8f00] x1:0 x2:1279 y1:0 y2:719 w:1280 h:720 x:0 y:0 pts:1081 t:1.081000 crop=1280:720:0:0
```

into just two substrings:

1. `[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0000000002ef8f00] x1:0 x2:1279 y1:0 y2:719 w:1280 h:720 x:0 y:0 pts:1081 t:1.081000 crop`
2. `1280:720:0:0`

Just the second substring is of interest which is the reason for using `tokens=2` to get assigned just `1280:720:0:0` to specified loop variable `J` which is assigned next to environment variable `CropData`. It is also possible to use the default string delimiters normal space and horizontal tab and assign fourteenth space/tab separated string to specified loop variable `J` using `"tokens=14"` which in this case includes `crop=` in string assigned finally to environment variable `CropData`.

There are multiple lines output by **FINDSTR** with `crop=` and so multiple lines are processed by inner **FOR** resulting in assigning multiple times crop data to environment variable `CropData`. That's okay because of wanted are just the last crop data.

The second command executed by outer **FOR** on each file outputs just the last crop data with the string `crop=`. The command **CALL** is used to force Windows command processor to parse the command line `echo crop %CropData%` as it is already after parsing the entire command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` at end before executing outer **FOR** a second time to real output the current value of environment variable `CropData`. See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Another solution would be using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as shown below.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.m?? /A-D-H /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ('"ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -ss 00:0:30.000 -i "%%I" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /c:"crop=""') do set "CropData=%%J"
    echo crop=!CropData!
)
endlocal
```

But this solution can be used only if no file name contains one or even more `!` as otherwise the exclamation mark(s) in file name would be interpreted as begin/end of an environment variable referenced and so the file name would not be correct passed to `ffmpeg.exe`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?` ... explains how double quotes in string(s) after option `/C` or `/K` are interpreted by Windows command processor and when a file name (or any other argument string) must be enclosed in `"` on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|> ``.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`