# FFmpeg: How to render horizontal non full hd video with black frames, to video in 1920x1080, with blurred background

Tags: video, ffmpeg, background, blur

Example video:

[image]

Desired results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full command may be as followed:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.jpg -filter_complex "scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,crop=1584:896:172:92,split[crp0][crp1];[crp0]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,gblur=sigma=30[blur];[blur][crp1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" out.jpg
```

The command applies the image you have posted (named `in.jpg`).

---

Sample output:
[image]

---

Chain of filters:

- `scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1` - Resize the input to 1920x1080 (`setsar` is used for fixing the aspect ratio).
- `crop=1584:896:172:92` - Crops the part inside the black frame.
- `split[crp0][crp1]` - Split the cropped output to two identical streams (two identical images).
- `[crp0]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,gblur=sigma=30[blur]` - Resize the cropped image to 1920x1080 and blur the resized image.
  Store the blurred image in the temporary variable `[blur]`.
- `[blur][crp1]overlay= ...` - Overlay `[crp1]` over the blurred image.

---

It works the same way for a video file.
Example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,crop=1584:896:172:92,split[crp0][crp1];[crp0]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,gblur=sigma=30[blur];[blur][crp1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec copy out.mp4
```

---

Finding the `crop` parameters using `cropdetect` filter:

Description of [cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-cropdetect) filter:

> Auto-detect the crop size.
> It calculates the necessary cropping parameters and prints the recommended parameters via the logging system.
> The detected dimensions correspond to the non-black area of the input video.

Using `cropdetect` result with Linux is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265381/ffmpeg-get-value-from-cropdetect).

I wanted to use it in Windows 10, and found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739280/get-value-from-cropdetect),
but it's not working...

---

The following code is working (with ffmpeg version 4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev):

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i in.jpg -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,cropdetect=skip=0 -t 1 -f null - 2>&1 | findstr /R /C:"crop=" > log.txt
for /F "tokens=14* delims= " %%i in (log.txt) do set crop=%%i
echo %crop%
```

Using `%crop%` with FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.jpg -filter_complex "scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,%crop%,split[crp0][crp1];[crp0]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,gblur=sigma=30[blur];[blur][crp1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" out.jpg
```

---

Batch file without writing to `log.txt`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=1
for /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%F in ('"ffmpeg -hide_banner -i in.jpg -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,cropdetect=skip=0 -t 1 -f null - 2>&1"') do (
  set var!count!=%%F
  set /a count=!count!+1
)
echo %var1%

ffmpeg -y -i in.jpg -filter_complex "scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,crop=%var1%,split[crp0][crp1];[crp0]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,gblur=sigma=30[blur];[blur][crp1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" out.jpg
endlocal
```